# Finding range of consecutive rows in Excel that yields the highest average sum

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that can contain anything from 10 to 200 rows. I want to cycle through all combinations of ranges (of three rows or more) to find the range of rows that yields the highest average.

For example, if my rows are:

12
1
4
18
9
3

... then starting with the A1:A3, then A1:A4 through to A1:A6, then moving on to A2:A4, then A2:A5, and so on, until all combinations of ranges of three rows or more have been Averaged. I would then like to either highlight, or even MsgBox the range with the highest average.

I know this is relatively simple, but it is really hurting my head. The 'winner' in the above scenario would be A3:A5 with 10.333, though I will stress that the range does not *have* to be 3 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
Sub bp()
Dim avg As Double
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i&, t&
Dim avgAdd As String
Set ws = ActiveSheet


With ws
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))


For i = 1 To rng.Rows.count - 2
    For t = i + 2 To rng.Rows.count
        If WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(t, 1))) > avg Then
            avg = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(t, 1)))
            avgAdd = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(t, 1)).Address
        End If
    Next
Next
MsgBox avgAdd & ":" & avg
End With

End Sub
```

I added a debug print every time that the average is larger.

[image]

Comment: I noticed it wasn't quite correct, I fixed the problem.  I had the ranges too large with the offsets of 3 instead of 2.  I should work now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Scott, I think this is only doing 3-row ranges. 3 rows should be the minimum range, but the maximum range should be the [total number of rows] - [starting row].

Comment: I have edited it and run it with your example.  It starts with 3 cells then goes up till it runs out of cells.  So it compares in this order A1:A3, A1:A4 A1:A5, A1:A6, A2:A4, A2:A5, A2:A6, A3:A5, A3:A6, A4:A6 and stops, it returns a msgbox saying `$A$3:$A$5:10.3333333333333`

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I can see that working now. I really appreciate you coming up with that so quickly. Thanks!